# Django - access class-based view's instance from middleware

Tags: python, django, middleware

I would like to do some stuff with views before actually processing them. I learned that `process_view` method of class-based middlewares might be helpful here. But the problem is that the only thing I managed to get from here is the actual class, but not its instance, which I would like to have.

Code approach is as follows:

```
class SomeView(View):
   class_attribute = "..."

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.instance_attribute = "..."
       # ...

class Middleware:
    # ...
    def process_view(request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        # access class_attribute
        print(view_func.view_class.class_attribute)

        # access instance_attribute 
        print("I don't know, please help, thank you.")
```

Comment: view_func is a function that constructs the class on calling. So at this point the class isn't initialized. Maybe if you share with us what you want to acomplish someone might be able to tell you a better way to do this.

Comment: So a simple answer is that this is impossible? I already have a solution for my problem, it includes a mixin with static attributes and methods and it works. But this would be much nicer.

Comment: In the middleware is not possible. You could still subclass the class View and look for a workaround but it's probably a bad idea